# Changing the encoding of a table with django+south migrations

Tags: python, django, django-south

Django and south newbie here

I need to change the encoding of a table I created, does anyone know a way to do so using a migration?

Comment: Are you trying to change the encoding of just one table or the entire database? What database are you using?

Comment: just one table. I'm using mysql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the solution will be database-specific. For example, for a MySQL database:

```
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import SchemaMigration

class Migration(SchemaMigration):
    def forwards(self, orm):
        db.execute('alter table appname_modelname charset=utf8')
        db.execute('alter table appname_modelname alter column fieldname charset=utf8')
        # et cetera for any other char or text columns

    def backwards(self, orm):
        db.execute('alter table appname_modelname charset=latin1')
        db.execute('alter table appname_modelname alter column fieldname charset=latin1')
        # et cetera for any other char or text columns

    complete_apps = ['appname']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, I'm now testing your suggestion. I was wondering, is there a way of doing this using manage.py schemamigration --auto? (i.e. just changing the models)